Are question about logical arguments in cognitive therapy on-topic?
The question How to disprove a social anxiety fear? is closed because it is about the behavior of an individual. I agree with the individual part, but the question is also about logic. If you use logic, then it should be universal and answerable.
Likewise, I think the answer just need to make a list of Socratic questions to help the OP. Such questions aren't subjective, and are helpful for future visitors. I think there are papers which list common questions to ask clients in specific cases. So not only this is answerable, it's also citable.
What do you think?

I also ask whether such a question is OK on Philosophy SE: Are questions about logical arguments in cognitive therapy on-topic?

Possibly.  There is a related question here: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10883/7001.  The referenced question however would need severe editing, or probably a complete re-write to focus on logical arguments in cognitive therapy.  Furthermore, I would recommend not making the assumption that such arguments are helpful - although this tactic may be used by therapists, I am not aware of much evidence to suggest that it is helpful to anxiety patients - so perhaps asking whether or not this strategy is even worth pursuing might make a better question.

is it because exposure is the way to deal with anxiety? But the OP says that exposure doesn't work for them

We don't know enough about the OP, that's why self-help questions are off-topic here.  Exposure Therapy is commonly used to treat phobias, but for social anxiety disorder, other treatments are available.
